# jQuery – simple image gallery with previous/next button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a simple jQuery image “gallery” which I adapted to my needs.

I’ve got a `<div id="gallery">` in which I define several `<img class="gallery">`’s.

And I’ve got a `<div id="gallery-nav">` with: `<span class="prev">` & `<span class="next">` which both have a `<p>` with text ("Previous"/"Next") inside.

The jQuery script should not do more than show the first of the specified images (so: “hide” the others) and on click of the “Previous”/“Next” symbol show the previous/next image.

**First question:** Maybe anyone of you knows a lot better/easier/faster solution to this approach.

**Second question:** Also I’d be happy to hear something about keyboard- and touchscreen-/swipe-support.

Here’s my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";
  $(".gallery").first().addClass("active");
  $(".gallery").hide();
  $(".active").show();

  $(".next").click(function () {
    $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("oldActive");

    if ($(".oldActive").is(":last-child")) {
      $(".gallery").first().addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".oldActive").next().addClass("active");
    }

    $(".oldActive").removeClass("oldActive");
    $(".gallery").fadeOut();
    $(".active").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".prev").click(function () {
    $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("oldActive");

    if ($(".oldActive").is(":first-child")) {
      $(".gallery").last().addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".oldActive").prev().addClass("active");
    }

    $(".oldActive").removeClass("oldActive");
    $(".gallery").fadeOut();
    $(".active").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Since you're asking for suggestions / commentary on working code, this is probably more appropriate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought about that, but because it's not ready yet (keyboard & touchscreen) I thought I'd have to ask it here.

Comment: Also it seems `$(".gallery").fadeOut(); $(".active").fadeIn();` does not work correctly. It fades out, but the suddenly the other image appears, withou fade effect. Any ideas? Are there alternatives to fade in and out?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest image galerie I've ever written, is this what you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="galerie">
                <td id="1" class="1"><img src="img/1.png" /></td>
                <td id="2" class="2" style="display:none;"><img src="img/2.png" /></td>
                <td id="3" class="3" style="display:none;"><img src="img/3.png" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="browseThrough(1)">picture 1</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="browseThrough(2)">picture 2</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" onclick="browseThrough(3)">picture 3</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function browseThrough(pictureId) {
                $("#galerie td").hide();
                $("td#"+pictureId).show()

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this example, Paul! I think the problem in which I would run with this method is, that it’s not dynamic. So I'd had to define every td with a unique ID and class and also the browseThrough need this value.